# Add paragraphs to a node via jsonapi

Tags: 8

Added a paragraph to drupal8 via jsonapi and want this paragraph to be in an articles body. I thought it is as easy as

```
    "relationships": {
        "field_body": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "type": "paragraph--text",
                    "id": "b0247bf8-a3c0-4a45-8e05-4f4901011000"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

but the article is created and the field_body result is empty. It works already with other entities just fine. And the jsonapi gives me the paragraph /jsonapi/paragraph/text ...What is the problem, am I missing something?

Comment: How did you added Paragraph using JSONapi?

Answer (score -1):

Did you gave node type ? Try the following body data.

```
{
 "data": 
  {
     "attributes": {
            "title": "title of your new node", 

        },
         "relationships": {
            "field_body": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "paragraph--text",
                    "id": "b0247bf8-a3c0-4a45-8e05-4f4901011000"
                }
            }
        },
      "type": "node--yournode"
    }
  }
```